# Java Factory Method/ Singleton pattern

Tags: design-patterns

Why is it a standard deign to implement Factory classes as singleton? What is wrong with this:

```
public class Factory{

public static createObjects(ObjectArgs arg){

return new Object(arg);
}
}
----
public class FactoryClient{

public void someMethod(){

Factory.createObjects(ObjectArgs arg);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing* wrong with creating static factory methods, and I see it fairly often.

* - That is, nothing wrong that isn't wrong with any static method (coupling, lack of testability, etc.). Consider using an [IoC Container](http://java-source.net/open-source/containers) and dependency injection instead of factories.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a singleton. It is a [factory-method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (it's not even a factory). There is nothing wrong in having a factory-method like that.